# Is there an efficient way to convert a pandas dataframe to a 3d numpy array 10 rows at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe that I need to convert to a a 3d numpy array where each 10 rows in the dataframe form a sub-array in the 3d numpy array. Say the dataframe has 10 columns and 1000 rows, the 3d numpy array should have the shape (100, 10, 10).

I have tried to use `to_numpy`, `numpy.concatenate` and several for loops but so far with little success.

I have tried something like this:

```
arr = [df.iloc[(idx*window):((idx+1)*window), 1:10].to_numpy() for idx in range(len(df))]
```

But this returns a list of separate arrays and I can't get it to convert to a 3d numpy array.

As described above I would expect the output or a 3d numpy array with shape (100, 10, 10)

Comment: `df.to_numpy().reshape((-1, 10, df.shape[1]))`?. Or if not a perfect division try `np.array_split(df.to_numpy(), df.shape[0]/10)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is not a perfect division, the second option you suggested, however, returns the same list as my solution: list of shape (10,10) arrays.